# From array, how to extract the value from each object using "for ..."

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I need help with this problem:

I have this array defined:

```
class VpnList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    vpn: [
      {
        nombre: 'Test1',
        activo: 'True',
        enlace: '#!',
      },
      {
        nombre: 'Test2',
        activo: 'False',
        enlace: '#!',
      },
      {
        nombre: 'Test3',
        activo: 'False',
        enlace: '#!',
      },
      {
        nombre: 'Test4',
        activo: 'False',
        enlace: '#!',
      }
    ]
  };
```

I am sending it to my react component: Like this

```
<MiTabs  data={this.state.vpn}/>
```

My component is receving correcty but I would to extrat inside a for only a determined key and obtain the value. (I only need the value).

I testing but is not correct:

```
const MiTabs = props => {
  console.log("MiTabs recibe props: " + props.data);
  console.log("MiTabs recibe props Tipo:: " + typeof props.data);




  function Welcome(recibo) {
    console.log("Welcome 1.0: " + typeof recibo);
    console.log("Welcome 1.1: ") ;

    for (let key in recibo) {
      console.log("Welcome 1.2: " + key, recibo[key]);
      const map = recibo[key];

      console.log("Welcome 1.3: " + Object.values(map[0]));

      for (let variable in recibo[key]){
        console.log("Welcome 1.4:  "+ recibo[variable])

        Object.entries(recibo[key]).forEach(entry => {
          let [key, value] = entry;
          console.log("Welcome 1.5: " + key, value[0]);
        })

      }
```

The Value that I need is: Test1, Test2....

Comment: you can use `map()` so it's `let values = this.props.data.map((item) => item.nombre);`

Comment: `vpn` is an array passed as `data` prop ... `nombre` is available as `props.data[0].nombre`, `props.data[1].nombre` ... use `map` to pass data sets ('items`) to individual components (render array)?

Answer (score 0):

This will get any values that you wants.

```
 const getItemValues = (items, key) {
     if (typeof items !== "object" || typeof key !== "string")
         return [];

     const _getValues = (values, items, key) {
         items.forEach((k, v) => {
             if (k === key) { values.push(v) }
             else if (typeof v === "object")
                 _getValues(values, v, key);
         });

         return values;
     };

     return _getValues([], items, key);
 };

console.log(getItemValues(codes, "OO7"));
```

Comment: Thanks to ALL. 
With all this solutions I have been able to make it work